I need complete code of Neural Network and gekko to optimize the ouput of neural network
I have never used python, I am new and need your help so that I can learn how to use. I have heat pumps data with 12 variables (with power consumption is one of the variables), I want to train my model in neural network with power consumption as ouput. I want to minimize power consumption by gekko so I need complete code of Neural Network and gekko to optimize the ouput of neural network.
Here is an example problem with one input and one output for demonstration purposes.

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Source function to generate data
def f(x):
    return np.cos(2*np.pi*x)

#represent noise from a data sample
N = 350
xl = np.linspace(0,1.2,N)
noise = np.random.normal(0,.3,N)
y_measured = f(xl) + noise

plt.figure(figsize=(6,3.5))
plt.plot(xl,f(xl),label='source function')
plt.plot(xl,y_measured,'.',label='measured points')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

Can a neural network model be fit to the data and then used in an optimization problem?

The skill will be in building a half decent model of how your "control" parameters affect the efficiency and power consumption of the heat pumps. Throwing it at a neural network and praying for a miracle is unlikely to work well. Neural networks are no substitute for properly understanding a physical problem. Chances are only a few of your twelve variable parameters make any real difference.

If the original function is known, Gekko can find the optimal solution such as:
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO()
x = m.Var(0,lb=0,ub=1)
y = m.Intermediate(m.cos(x*2*np.pi)) #function is used here
m.Obj(y)
m.solve(disp=False)
print('solution:',y.value[0])
print('x:',x.value[0])

That gives a minimum to the original function at x=0.5. If a function is not known, but needs to be regressed from data, there are many different model forms. Neural networks are one, but there are other types that may be worthwhile. A general flowchart for building a Machine Learned model is shown in this flowchart from the Machine Learning for Engineers course.

A first step is to consolidate, visualize, and assess the features (inputs) to determine which ones are highly correlated with the output. More details on this overall process are shown in the Wind Power case study. Once the data is cleansed and scaled, train with scikit-learn or tensorflow and then import into Gekko.
Train with scikit-learn
import pandas as pd
from gekko.ML import Gekko_NN_SKlearn, CustomMinMaxGekkoScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor

#Training the Data and split it
data = pd.DataFrame(np.array([xl,y_measured]).T,columns=['x','y'])
features = ['x']
label = ['y']

train,test = train_test_split(data,test_size=0.2,shuffle=True)

s = CustomMinMaxGekkoScaler(data,features,label)
ds = s.scaledData()
mma = s.minMaxValues()

trains,tests = train_test_split(ds,test_size=0.2,shuffle=True)
hl= [25,15]
mlp = MLPRegressor(hidden_layer_sizes= hl, activation='relu',
                   solver='adam', batch_size = 32,
                   learning_rate = 'adaptive',learning_rate_init = .0005,
                   tol=1e-6 ,n_iter_no_change = 200,
                   max_iter=12000)
mlp.fit(trains[features],np.ravel(trains[label]))
r2 = mlp.score(tests[features],np.ravel(tests[label]))
print('nnSK r2:',r2)

Optimize NN Model with Gekko
Now import the scikit-learn NN model into gekko and optimize:
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO()
x = m.Var(0,lb=0,ub=1)
y = Gekko_NN_SKlearn(mlp,mma,m).predict([x])
m.Obj(y)
m.solve(disp=False)
print('solution:',y.value[0])
print('x:',x.value[0])
print('Gekko Solvetime:',m.options.SOLVETIME,'s')

This gives a solution that is close to the original solution of 0.5.
x: 0.49272077892
Gekko Solvetime: 0.11490000002 s

This problem can be adapted to your problem with 12 inputs. Additional information on using tensorflow, gpflow, and scikit-learn models with gekko is available in the Gekko documentation.

Respected Sir, Last code is working with 1 variable, it is not working with 2 variables
Here is the link of my code, last code is not working.
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1bYsbUOgNfALLWQiRm_DWPsv5apWS0PL5?usp=sharing

Try upgrading to the latest version of Gekko with pip install gekko --upgrade

Respected sir I have tried but I think the code will be different for 2 variables , I want to minimize power consumption (Pel) by chosing two or more decision variables

I am facing this error when use 2 variables
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (11,) (2,)

Thanks for asking the follow-up question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78363229/this-code-is-working-when-one-variable-at-the-end-in-gekko-is-using-it-is-not-w
